# Looping through XElement items

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I've the following XML:

```
<ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>
<CustomerOrderExportInfo>
<ID>168</ID>
<CustomerOrderLines>
<CustomerOrderExportInfo>
<Amount>1522</Amount>
</CustomerOrderExportInfo>
<CustomerOrderExportInfo>
<Amount>1522</Amount>
</CustomerOrderExportInfo>
...
</CustomerOrderLines>
</CustomerOrderExportInfo>
</ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>
```

I loop through this like this:

```
using System.Linq
using System.XML.Linq

Stream xmlUpload = <file>

var customerOrders = from co in 
                      XElement.Load(xmlUpload).Eelements("CustomerOrderExportInfo")
select co;

xmlUpload.Close
foreach(var orderXML in customerOrders)
{
    int orderID = Convert.ToInt32(orderXML.Element("ID").Value);

}
```

This gives me ID 168 fine.

Now I want to loop through the CustomerOrderExportInfo items in the existing foreach loop and then it fails.

I've tried

```
var customerOrderLine = orderXML.Descendants("CustomerOrderExportInfo")
```

but this gives an empty collection.
Also various kind of orderXML.Nodes() but always empty collection.

Pointers and help appreciated

Kind regards

Jeroen

Comment: Try this : foreach(var orderXML in customerOrders.FirstOrDefault().Descendants("CustomerOrderExportInfo"))

Comment: Not exactly what I want. I like to loop with the forach loop more like forach(var line in orderXML.Descendants ...

Comment: Probaly the FirstOrDefault would have given me a single element for my next step.

Comment: Wrong. customerOrders is a List object with only one item.  You need FirstOrDefault to get the single List Item.  Then use Descendants to get all the CustomerOrderEx‌​portInfo orders.

Comment: Are you aware that you have <CustomerOrderExportInfo>, inside of <CustomerOrderExportInfo> ?  Is that intentional?  Do you want <ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>.<CustomerOrderExportInfo>  or <ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>.<CustomerOrderExportInfo>.CustomerOrderLines>.<CustomerOrderExportInfo>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny,

if i try to place it in a variable it fails:

```
var test = orderXML.Descendants("CustomerOrderLineExportInfo");
```

but like so:

```
foreach(var orderLine in orderXML.Descendants("CustomerOrderLineExportInfo"))
{
    ...
}
```

i can loop through the records

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the VB...  The first part is loading the XElement.  Sadly C# doesn't allow for XML literals. (If I were a C# programmer I would have to have a VB module just to be able to have XML literals ;)

Added some data for test.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from a file
    '  xe = XElement.Load("Your Path Here")

    ' for testing
    xe = <ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>
             <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                 <ID>168</ID>
                 <CustomerOrderLines>
                     <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                         <Amount>1522</Amount>
                     </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                     <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                         <Amount>2522</Amount>
                     </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                 </CustomerOrderLines>
             </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
             <!-- for testing -->
             <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                 <ID>9999</ID>
                 <CustomerOrderLines>
                     <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                         <Amount>991</Amount>
                     </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                     <CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                         <Amount>992</Amount>
                     </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
                 </CustomerOrderLines>
             </CustomerOrderExportInfo>
         </ArrayOfCustomerOrderExportInfo>
```

Once it is loaded you can do a lot of interesting things.  The first is to get all of the outer CustomerOrderExportInfo.

```
    Dim outerCOI As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    outerCOI = xe.<CustomerOrderExportInfo>
```

Then you could look at them and get the inner CustomerOrderExportInfo

```
    Dim innerCOI As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    For Each el As XElement In outerCOI
        innerCOI = el...<CustomerOrderExportInfo>
    Next
```

Finally if you just want to get ALL of the CustomerOrderExportInfo inside of CustomerOrderExportInfo you could just do this.  Note how you can access the ID from the elements.

```
    innerCOI = xe.<CustomerOrderExportInfo>...<CustomerOrderExportInfo>

    For Each el As XElement In innerCOI
        Debug.WriteLine(el.Parent.Parent.<ID>.Value)
        Debug.WriteLine(el.<Amount>.Value)
    Next
```